# How do I deploy my completed IntraWeb Delphi application to the Web/Network?

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo, intraweb

I built a simple IntraWeb website client, with Delphi 10.2 and IntraWeb 14, that reads and writes data via a REST Server. On my local machine, it works great, but deploying it to the company server is seemingly a problem. How does one actually deploy an IntraWeb website/client app to a Windows Server? Just copying over the files to the server does not work.

Below are the results from my attempts. I also cannot seem to find any documentation from AToZed on Intraweb. Google provides links to docs.atozed.com pages that no longer exist. Is IntraWeb that bad, that their own publishers don't bother publishing "how to" and other support documents, or am I missing something? ;-)

On my company's Windows server machine, once my new IntraWeb server app is running, I can access the webpage(s) in most web browsers (except IE, as always) with the built-in localhost address and whichever port Intraweb chose on the fly. Like http://127.0.0.1:61437/$/start

When I try, in a local web browser, to access this IntraWeb website/webpage now running on my company server, I get the following issues:

1. When using the local computer IP (LAN assigned IP), I get connection refused errors
2. When I try using the public IP address of the Windows Server, with the port provided by the running IW Client Web Server, I get connection timed out
3. When I try to access the public IP with the port # 8888 (default?), it also cannot find the site

Where can I find some documents on how to deploy (completed) Intraweb website clients? Does anybody here maybe have tips on the steps that should be followed with IW for deployment?

Comment: You should ask these questions in AToZed's [IntraWeb support forum](https://www.atozed.com/forums/forum-16.html). In the meantime, I have reported the broken doc links to AToZed. They were having problems with their hosting provider a few months ago, maybe this is related.

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you very much. I have actually been waiting for days to get an answer on Intraweb's forums, to no avail. That's why I felt I may have better luck with answers here, but I guess I was wrong about that also. Too bad I can't get any help on StackOverflow either. Is there perhaps another website/forum, like this one, I should use for Delphi/Intraweb questions. Is stackoverflow only for other technologies, or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you are not doing anything wrong here. It is just that IntraWeb questions have very low traffic on StackOverflow. The IntraWeb forum has more traffic, and the authors hang out there. But I don't see any recent post from you on the forum. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 1):

There is significant documentation about IntraWeb application deployment here:

http://docs.atozed.com/Docs.dll/deployment/index.html

All that an IntraWeb application needs is the executable (the EXE in case of Stand Alone applications, or the DLL in case of ISAPI modules) plus all content files that you might be using inside application's own wwwroot folder (images, custom scripts, etc.).

That's all.

According to your report, the "random port issue" happens because you don't have a proper license installed (i.e. your executable is not linked with a valid license when it's being built). IntraWeb will work in Demo mode and that's why you keep getting "Connection refused" error messages: In demo mode IntraWeb will only serve content from a local request (i.e. from the same machine).

This specific situation is also described in this document here:

http://docs.atozed.com/Docs.dll/technical%20information/Evaluating%20IntraWeb.html

So, I recommend that you start sorting out the license issue which will allow you to set a fixed port in ServerController and it will also allow your application to respond to remote requests.

Also, if you are not using a conventional port (80, 443 for HTTPS, etc.) make sure that the port is open in Windows firewall. Windows will definitely block any incoming request to a port such as 8888.